# C++ 3rd party library includes non existing header file?

Tags: c++, c, linux, string

*First things first: I'm a newbie in C/C++.*

I have a library that I have to include but it has header files that use

```
#include <string>
```

I tried to include `<string>` but it failed. I can

```
#include <string.h>
```

though. Since it's a library I'm trying to use I can't do much about this import right ? How can I fix this problem ? Build terminates with a fatal error.

*(In case that's important I'm working on Linux and **genicam** is the 3rd party library)*

Comment: Is this C or C++ they are different languages and the answer will differ depending on which - I would also suggest looking at a tutorial as that will answer the question as to which header you should use

Comment: Are you writing C or C++? It sounds like you might be trying to use a C++ library in a C program, which won't work since they're different languages. (You can often use C libraries from C++, but usually not the other way round). If you are writing C++, then make sure you're using a C++ compiler (e.g. `g++`, not `gcc`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<string>` is a standard C++ header. Either your compiler is broken, or installed incorrectly, or you are trying to use a C compiler on C++ code (for instance by using gcc instead of g++).

Comment: There is no such language as 'C/C++', if your project is C++ then you should use g++.